# Getting Python Output Dictionary with calculations

Tags: python, counter, dictionary-comprehension

I am new to Python and to StackOverflow. I am currently busy studying Python Online, and I need to complete a project which requires very specific outputs from the Python code in order to continue with the project.
I have been stuck in a question for over a week and I cant find the solution. So any help is more than welcome.

We are coming from this data (datos_lista):

```
('23', 'RETIRO', 'Despejado', (25, 29), 0)
('22', 'MONCLOA-ARAVACA', 'Despejado', (21, 24), 6)
('20', 'FUENCARRAL-EL PARDO', 'Despejado', (45, 49), 14)
('20', 'FUENCARRAL-EL PARDO', 'Despejado', (25, 29), 7)
('20', 'FUENCARRAL-EL PARDO', 'Despejado', (25, 29), 4)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrlcY.png)

What we need to do is:

1. datos_lista[3] group by (AgeRange = (21,24),...):

Group by Age Range ((25, 29),(21, 24),(45, 49),...)

2. datos_lista[3] count:

Count the amount of times that the AgeRange appears.

3. And, 3- datos_lista[4]== Count if == 4:

Count the amount of times that datos_lista[4]== 4
(In the example above this only appears once in the last line)
(('20', 'FUENCARRAL-EL PARDO', 'Despejado', (25, 29), **4**))

And the question requires me to provide this output:

[Output required](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Csncn.png)

All of this needs to work on this "code check":

"""# Prueba de funcionamiento1:

```
total_accidentes_y_muertes_por_edades = totales_mortales(datos_lista)

for k, totales in total_accidentes_y_muertes_por_edades.items: print(k, totales)
print()
```

"""# Prueba de funcionamiento2:

```
tasa_accidentes_mortales_por_mil = [(k, m*1000/n) for k, (n, m) in total_accidentes_y_muertes_por_edades.items()]

for k_tasa  in tasa_accidentes_mortales_por_mil:
print(k_tasa)
```

"""

I have been able to generate the code separately and match the solution, but neither of them pass the "code check" or produces the output together.

Codes Attempts:

1-

```
def totales (datos_lista):
from collections import Counter
totales1 = Counter()

for p in datos_lista:
    totales1[p[3]] += 1


return(totales1)
```

2-

```
def totales2 (datos_lista):

from collections import Counter
from collections import defaultdict

totales2 = Counter()
for q in datos_lista:
    if q [4] == 4:
        totales2[q[3]] += 1

return(totales2)
```

Thank you very much in advance,
(please if anything is unclear let me know, I am new to this so I do not know how to formulate it properly to make it clear enough)
Daniel

Comment: Can you describe this part of `What we need to do is` in more detail, the second and third items of the current information are not clear.

Comment: Hi there, Apologies for that... I have included some extra comments in there... Hope those make the explanation easier to understand

What we need to do is:

datos_lista[3] group by (AgeRange = (21,24),...):
Group by Age Range ((25, 29),(21, 24),(45, 49),...)

datos_lista[3] count:
Count the amount of times that the AgeRange appears.

And, 3- datos_lista[4]== Count if == 4:
Count the amount of times that datos_lista[4]== 4 (In the example above this only appears once in the last line) (('20', 'FUENCARRAL-EL PARDO', 'Despejado', (25, 29), 4))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with your `Prueba de funcionamiento1` code, `total_accidentes_y_muertes_por_edades.items` is a method, you don't call it, and you do a for loop over it, so it will throw an exception.

According to your description of the problem, I define the function `totales2` and get the output.

```py
datos_lista = [
    ('23', 'RETIRO', 'Despejado', (25, 29), 0),
    ('22', 'MONCLOA-ARAVACA', 'Despejado', (21, 24), 6),
    ('20', 'FUENCARRAL-EL PARDO', 'Despejado', (45, 49), 14),
    ('20', 'FUENCARRAL-EL PARDO', 'Despejado', (25, 29), 7),
    ('20', 'FUENCARRAL-EL PARDO', 'Despejado', (25, 29), 4)
]


def totales2(datos_lista):
    counter = {}
    for *_, age_range, c in datos_lista:
        t = counter.setdefault(age_range, [0, 0])
        t[0] += 1
        if c == 4:
            t[1] += 1
    return counter


total_accidentes_y_muertes_por_edades = totales2(datos_lista)

for k, totales in total_accidentes_y_muertes_por_edades.items():
    print(k, totales)

print()


tasa_accidentes_mortales_por_mil = [(k, m*1000/n) for k, (n, m) in total_accidentes_y_muertes_por_edades.items()]

for k_tasa in tasa_accidentes_mortales_por_mil:
    print(k_tasa)
```

Output:

```
(25, 29) [3, 1]
(21, 24) [1, 0]
(45, 49) [1, 0]

((25, 29), 333.3333333333333)
((21, 24), 0.0)
((45, 49), 0.0)
```

Comment: Hi pppig , thank you very much for the above! Your approach is way simpler and efficient!!

I will also amend "Prueba de Funcionamiento1" !!